# How to declare a property of type boolean or () => boolean

Tags: typescript

I am trying to declare a property in my interface as

```
export interface GridColumn {
  isRequired?: boolean | (row: any) => boolean
}
```

I am getting error saying `false is not assignable to type (row: any) => boolean`

Can anyone correct me if this is wrong way of declaring?

Comment: What code is showing that error? Surely not the interface defintion.

Comment: Put parentheses around the function type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgcSgQBMBhCAGwFcBbJOAbwFgAoORAZwCVgBHKhFGDEA-AC44AIwiVgmegB84ACmVQIAdwnyAngEo4AXgB8UmRTlI9AblYBfVq2wQkHeAHNsARiOM7tlmdXD2wAJl9mNnZOHn5BYQkYKCpgABp7AKC3OE8AZgjWaJi+ASFiCWUDEzgklPSWf1YgA. Note that that's going to be a really annoying property to use, you'll constantly be checking "do I need to call this or not?"

Comment: Don't do this. I know typescript will let you, but just don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parantheses are required for this case

```
 export interface GridColumn {
      isRequired?: boolean | ((row: any) => boolean)
    }
    
    const obj: GridColumn = { isRequired: true };
    const obj2: GridColumn = { isRequired: () => true };
```

I'd suggest writing a helper function for when you need to check this property, since it can be quite a hassle

```
function isRequired(obj: GridColumn, row?: any): boolean {
  return typeof obj.isRequired === "function" ? obj.isRequired(row) : obj.isRequired ?? false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you the declaration with () worked.